# Need 2 thumbnail rows as nav for 1 large slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I get issue with my slider, asNavFor working wrong. I want when to click arrow buttons thumbnail, slider to change one by one item inside and change too large slider and reverse. Thank you for help

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/h0u8vyrx/1/]


[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/h0u8vyrx/1/
```

Comment: And what exactly is your issue?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried so far? Read through [How to Ask a Quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to turn the jsfiddle url into a link, if the editor is telling you that you can't have that without some code in the question, pick the most relevant portion of code to include.

Comment: I don't know how to add the jsfiddle? There is the first I post in stackoverflow

Comment: @RalfFriedl I just want to need your help to fix help me slider.